# Keyboard recognised by OS but does not work

Tags: keyboard, asus

Keyboard not working in Ubuntu or Mint. Could this be the problem. I have had this problem since trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 3 days ago. Cant do anything without a key board. It's possibly a kernel issue.

I faced the same issue, and found workaround for now.
Before updating kernel:

Edit file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`

Add next lines:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Asus WMI hotkeys"
        MatchProduct "Asus WMI hotkeys"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
```

Comment: welcome to U&L, is it a self answered question ? this is fine here, however, you should post answer part as answer, wait a bit and accept it.

Comment: margaret, if the contents of 00-keyboard.conf worked for you, would you please follow Archemar's suggestion and put them into an Answer? Thank you!